# How can i pass the variable inside the tag through .html() jquery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the sample code :

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
    var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var numbers = result.length;
    $('div[class="new"]').html('<h1>numbers</h1>');
});
```

where I want to display all variables within different tags.
Right now i am only getting numbers as output on my DOM?
how can i get the value of numbers in DOM?

Comment: `html('<h1>'+numbers+'</h1>');` - string concatenation!

Answer (score 4):

Simple string concatenation

```
$('div[class="new"]').html('<h1>' + numbers + '</h1>');
```

Comment: @SohilShah : glad to help :)